# Getting Twitter news feed using Python

Tags: python, twitter, urllib2, beautifulsoup, urllib

Hey everybody, I've been playing around with Python 2.7 and BeautifulSoup 3.2 recently and I've gotten my code to work for Facebook where it makes a POST request to Facebook to login and downloads the HTML to the page, then saves it to my computer. I tried doing this with Twitter but it doesn't seem to be working*.. here's my code:

```
import urllib, urllib2
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

#I've replaced my actual username and password for obvious reasons
form = urllib.urlencode({'username':'myUsername','password':'myPassword'})
response = urllib2.urlopen('https://mobile.twitter.com/session',form)
response = response.read()
```

Can anyone tell me what's wrong with it? Thanks!

*After I do response = response.read() I have it write to a file on my harddrive and open it with firefox. When I open it all I see is whatever is on http://mobile.twitter.com/ at the time of me running the script.

Comment: When you say it’s not working, what do you mean? What results do you see?

Comment: After I do response = response.read() I have it write to a file on my harddrive and open it with firefox. When I open it all I see is whatever is on http://mobile.twitter.com/ at the time of me running the script.

Comment: why dont you use a better api ? http://dev.twitter.com/pages/libraries#python   ?

Comment: okay, sure. Funnily enough, I get the same behaviour when trying that in Firefox. I’m not sure if they’re doing some sort of client or server check to see whether you’re a mobile browser, and redirecting to the home page if you’re not?

Answer (score 2):

- Don't use BeatufulSoup, use lxml instead http://lxml.de/ (much more powerfull, faster and convenient)
- Don't grab twitter web-interface, use oficial twitter API instead http://dev.twitter.com/doc/get/statuses/home_timeline

Comment: Agreed - you can use oauth2 library along with urllib2 to do the authentication.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check out the [Twitter libraries for Python](http://code.activestate.com/pypm/search%3atwitter/).